# Uninstall VirtualBox before uninstalling Ubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, virtualbox

I have installed VirtualVox VM and then installed Ubuntu.

Then after some days I uninstalled VirtualBox from add/remove program. But I didn't uninstall the Ubuntu that is installed in VirtualBox.

Now I am seeing `VirtualBox VMs` folder in my PC users folder.

What can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing Virtual Box means you remove the application. Still some apps keep  files even after uninstalling, and VBox  is one of them.

The directory you see includes the hdd of the old machines and the configuration files so you can rerun your old machines if you install VBox again.

So, for you its up to you, if you don't need that machine anymore you can easily remove that directory with its content.

Answer (score 2):

This is no problem. You can simply delete the folder `VirtualBox VMs`.

Inside this folder are the configuration files of VirtualBox and the virtual HDDs.

You can also leave that folder and reuse the virtual machine later if you want.